# Ubuntu top menu size decreased after enabling "large text" mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, icons, gnome

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and encountered strange issue.
By default my top menu looks like this:
[image]

However, after enabling "large text" mode, the size of menu decreased:
[image]

And after disabling "large text":
[image]

What's going on? How to fix this?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [ubuntu.se]  or [su], but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm using the same Ubuntu 20.04 and large text setting is working as expected, I would advise you to update your system and see if the problem persists.

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Comment: Nothing has updated. Consequently, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269979/display-text-too-large-on-startup-possible-gui-driver-issues

```
sudo apt install libmutter-6-0=3.36.1-3ubuntu3 gir1.2-mutter-6=3.36.1-3ubuntu3 sudo 
apt-mark hold libmutter-6-0
```